# Soft/Hard question on the relation of homology of finite covering spaces and the base (for singular homology, Morse homology and ECH)

Tags: algebraic-topology, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory, contact-topology

I would like to know how much is to be expected from the relation of the homology of a $n$-sheeted covering manifold $M$ and its base $N$ (let's say $\pi:M\mapsto N, deg \space\pi=n$).

I'm interested in this question at some different layers, first of all, what is the relation of the complexes $C_M$ and $C_N$ (other than sometimes a surjection induced by $\pi$)? Does this map induced by $\pi$ commutes with the respective differentials in $C_M$ and $C_N$? And how much information can we gain at the homology level? (in any sense, information of $N$ known $M$, and viceversa).

Any help is welcome, I'm interested in this question for three specific homologies ranging form less difficult to more difficult: singular homology, Morse homology and Embedded Contact Homology (ECH).

Comment: There are various things available in this setup. Look up "transfer homomorphism" in Hatcher's textbook for instance. You also have (atleast if $M$ and $N$ are compact) a pushforward map $H^*(M) \to H^*(N)$, which in top degree should be multiplication by $n$, see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64744/how-should-one-think-about-pushforward-in-cohomology.